# Running a subexpression once

Tags: haskell, optimization

OK, so this has been bothering me for a while, so I thought I'd come and ask somebody who might actually know the answer.

Suppose I have the following function:

```
foobar x y = expensive x + cheap y
```

Suppose, further, that part of the program takes `foobar 5` as input, and executes this function millions of times in a tight loop. Clearly, I want `expensive 5` to be computed once, not a million times.

I could leave the code as it is, or I could change it to

```
foobar x = let k = expensive x in \ y -> k + cheap y
```

This leaves me wondering...

- Is GHC smart enough to eliminate the duplicated work by itself? (I.e., does the first version do what I want already?)
- If no, does the second version actually fix the problem? (I.e., will the optimiser just transform it back into the same code as the first version?)

Comment: Doesn't this potentially change semantics, `map (foo 5) []; foo a b = undefined a + b` If you force the evaluation of `foo 5` for the map, you'll blow up unnecessarily

Comment: @jozefg The `let` doesn't force the evaluation. It is evaluated when it's needed the first time (and then hopefully shared for all further uses).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Is GHC smart enough to eliminate the duplicated work by itself? (I.e., does the first version do what I want already?)
```

I think another way of asking this is: *Will GHC inline `foobar x y` so that `expensive x` is shared between computations*?

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690146/why-does-ghc-consider-the-lhs-syntactically-when-inlining) which cleared up a few things but left me a little unsatisfied. As I understand it, determining how and when to inline or eta-expand/reduce things (and when doing so subtly changes strictness behavior/semantics) is really tricky for the compiler, so GHC relies heavily on how you've defined your function syntactically.

I think the short answer is that GHC *might* transform your first function to the second, but the only way to be sure is to write your functions so the syntax gives the compiler hints about how you'd like things to be inlined to get the sharing you want, and then provide `INLINE` pragmas. Here's another [interesting discussion of this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fa.haskell/LEFHMgwCO4g)

Comment: So, essentially, the main answer is "if you care which one it is, you should explicitly write the second version" (?)

Comment: If anyone is interested I just posted an old idea for an alternate inlining syntax as a  [GHC feature request](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8099). would be interested in whether it makes sense or seems like a good idea to anyone.

Answer (score 7):

Intuitively my answer would have been *no*, and *yes*. But let me answer you question by trying it out. Consider this code:

```
import Debug.Trace

expensive :: Int -> Int
expensive x = trace ("expensive evaluated for " ++ show x) $ x
{-# NOINLINE expensive #-}

cheap :: Int -> Int
cheap x = x
{-# NOINLINE cheap #-}

foobar x y = expensive x + cheap y

foobar' x = let k = expensive x in \ y -> k + cheap y

part f = sum [f i| i<-[0..10]]

main = do
    print $ part (foobar 5)
    print $ part (foobar' 5)
```

If we run this the result is

```
$ ./Test 
expensive evaluated for 5
110
expensive evaluated for 5
110
```

so the compiler was smart enough to optimize the original version as well. But why? Because he inlined the definition of `foobar` in `main`, then noticed that it could float the expression `expensive 5` out of the call to `part`. If we disable inlining for `foobar` and `foobar'` (or alternatively not use `-O`), it does not work any more:

```
$ ./Test 
expensive evaluated for 5
expensive evaluated for 5
expensive evaluated for 5
expensive evaluated for 5
expensive evaluated for 5
expensive evaluated for 5
expensive evaluated for 5
expensive evaluated for 5
expensive evaluated for 5
expensive evaluated for 5
expensive evaluated for 5
110
expensive evaluated for 5
110
```

So while GHC can in some situations do the right thing, you should always check if it is the case if you want to rely on it. Either using tools like `Debug.Trace`, or by looking at the core (`-ddump-simpl`).

Answer (score 0):

Reading one of the various STG papers, it appears that this is the so-called *full laziness transformation*. It seems that [at the time the paper was written] GHC *does* apply this transformation, but not all the time, since it can result in space leaks.

Canonical example:

```
foo x = map f [1..1000000]
```

If we transform this into

```
foo x = map f big

big = [1..1000000]
```

we now have one giant CAF hanging around forever - which probably isn't what the programmer intended! (I have personally been bitten in this exact way, actually...)