# Why do these fixpoint cata / ana morphism definitions outperform the recursive ones?

Tags: performance, haskell, recursion, optimization, benchmarking

Consider these definitions from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48705438/2108477):

```
type Algebra f a = f a -> a

cata :: Functor f => Algebra f b -> Fix f -> b
cata alg = alg . fmap (cata alg) . unFix

fixcata :: Functor f => Algebra f b -> Fix f -> b
fixcata alg = fix $ \f -> alg . fmap f . unFix

type CoAlgebra f a = a -> f a

ana :: Functor f => CoAlgebra f a -> a -> Fix f
ana coalg = Fix . fmap (ana coalg) . coalg

fixana :: Functor f => CoAlgebra f a -> a -> Fix f
fixana coalg = fix $ \f -> Fix . fmap f . coalg
```

I ran some benchmarks and the results are surprising me. `criterion` reports something like a tenfold speedup, specifically when `O2` is enabled. I wonder what causes such massive improvement, and begin to seriously doubt my benchmarking abilities.

This is the exact `criterion` code I use:

```
smallWord, largeWord :: Word
smallWord = 2^10
largeWord = 2^20

shortEnv, longEnv :: Fix Maybe
shortEnv = ana coAlg smallWord
longEnv = ana coAlg largeWord

benchCata = nf (cata alg)
benchFixcata = nf (fixcata alg)

benchAna = nf (ana coAlg)
benchFixana = nf (fixana coAlg)

main = defaultMain
    [ bgroup "cata"
        [ bgroup "short input"
            [ env (return shortEnv) $ \x -> bench "cata"    (benchCata x)
            , env (return shortEnv) $ \x -> bench "fixcata" (benchFixcata x)
            ]
        , bgroup "long input"
            [ env (return longEnv) $ \x -> bench "cata"    (benchCata x)
            , env (return longEnv) $ \x -> bench "fixcata" (benchFixcata x)
            ]
        ]
    , bgroup "ana"
        [ bgroup "small word"
            [ bench "ana" $ benchAna smallWord
            , bench "fixana" $ benchFixana smallWord
            ]
        , bgroup "large word"
            [ bench "ana" $ benchAna largeWord
            , bench "fixana" $ benchFixana largeWord
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

And some auxiliary code:

```
alg :: Algebra Maybe Word
alg Nothing = 0
alg (Just x) = succ x

coAlg :: CoAlgebra Maybe Word
coAlg 0 = Nothing
coAlg x = Just (pred x)
```

Compiled with `O0`, the digits are pretty even. With `O2`, `fix~` functions seem to outperform the plain ones:

```
benchmarking cata/short input/cata
time                 31.67 μs   (31.10 μs .. 32.26 μs)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 31.20 μs   (31.05 μs .. 31.46 μs)
std dev              633.9 ns   (385.3 ns .. 1.029 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 18% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking cata/short input/fixcata
time                 2.422 μs   (2.407 μs .. 2.440 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 2.399 μs   (2.388 μs .. 2.410 μs)
std dev              37.12 ns   (31.44 ns .. 47.06 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 14% (moderately inflated)
```

I would appreciate if someone can confirm or spot a flaw.

*I compiled things with `ghc 8.2.2` on this occasion.)

---

**postscriptum**

[This post from back in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12999385/2108477) elaborates on the performance of `fix` in quite a fine detail. (Thanks to `@chi` for the link.)

Comment: Note that [*recursion-schemes* defines `cata`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2/docs/src/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#Recursive) as `cata f = c where c = f . fmap c . project`  (as opposed to `cata f = f . fmap (cata f) . project`) due to, I presume, the same issue discussed in the postscript link. Cf. also [*why pipes defines inner functions*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31168743/2751851).

Comment: Note that for the longer input, the `fix` variants only outperform their non-fix counterparts by a factor of 5 to 6.

Comment: FWIW, allocations are similar for `-O0` (the non-`fix` variants have only 1.31x the allocations) but quite different for `-O2` (the non-`fix` variants have 2.75x the allocations). That seems to support the hypothesis that the non-`fix` variant might be recomputing some things instead of sharing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to [how the fixed point is computed by `fix`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12999385/2108477).
This was pointed out by @duplode above (and by myself in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705438/can-one-express-catamorphism-through-data-function-fix)). Anyway, we can summarize the issue as follows.

We have that

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

works, but makes a `fix f` new call at every recursion. Instead,

```
fix f = go
   where go = f go
```

computes the same fixed point avoiding that call. In the libraries `fix` is implemented in this more efficient way.

Back to the question, consider the following *three* implementations of `cata`:

```
cata :: Functor f => Algebra f b -> Fix f -> b
cata alg' = alg' . fmap (cata alg') . unFix

cata2 :: Functor f => Algebra f b -> Fix f -> b
cata2 alg' = go
   where
   go = alg' . fmap go . unFix

fixcata :: Functor f => Algebra f b -> Fix f -> b
fixcata alg' = fix $ \f -> alg' . fmap f . unFix
```

The first one makes a call `cata alg'` at every recursion. The second one does not. The third one also does not since the library `fix` is efficient.

And indeed, we can use Criterion to confirm this, even using the same test used by the OP:

```
benchmarking cata/short input/cata
time                 16.58 us   (16.54 us .. 16.62 us)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 16.62 us   (16.58 us .. 16.65 us)
std dev              111.6 ns   (89.76 ns .. 144.0 ns)

benchmarking cata/short input/cata2
time                 1.746 us   (1.742 us .. 1.749 us)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 1.741 us   (1.736 us .. 1.744 us)
std dev              12.69 ns   (10.50 ns .. 17.31 ns)

benchmarking cata/short input/fixcata
time                 2.010 us   (2.003 us .. 2.016 us)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 2.006 us   (2.001 us .. 2.011 us)
std dev              16.40 ns   (14.05 ns .. 19.27 ns)
```

Long inputs also show the improvement.

```
benchmarking cata/long input/cata
time                 119.3 ms   (113.4 ms .. 125.8 ms)
                     0.996 R²   (0.992 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 119.8 ms   (117.7 ms .. 121.7 ms)
std dev              2.924 ms   (2.073 ms .. 4.064 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 11% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking cata/long input/cata2
time                 17.89 ms   (17.43 ms .. 18.36 ms)
                     0.996 R²   (0.992 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 18.02 ms   (17.49 ms .. 18.62 ms)
std dev              1.362 ms   (853.9 us .. 2.022 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 33% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking cata/long input/fixcata
time                 18.03 ms   (17.56 ms .. 18.50 ms)
                     0.996 R²   (0.992 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 18.17 ms   (17.57 ms .. 18.72 ms)
std dev              1.365 ms   (852.1 us .. 2.045 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 33% (moderately inflated)
```

I also experimented with `ana`, observing that the performance of a similarly improved `ana2` agrees with `fixana`. No surprises there as well.

Comment: Well, but there is still the recursive call to `go`. That it is not a top-level binding does not mean it is not a lambda abstraction. According to benchmarks, it must be the case that top-level recursion causes tenfold performance loss comparing to `let`-recursion, but I will still be seeking the explanation of the underlying *computational* differences, be they lying on the STG level or even deeper. After all, `cata2` is no less recursive than `cata`, in that it conains recursion, "encapsulated" in `go` but nevertheless.

Comment: In any way, it's great that we can now stop talking about particular functions and move on to researching why GHC optimizes top-level and `let`-level recursion differently.

Comment: @Kindaro Well, `go` takes no arguments, while `cata` takes one. Recursions like `go = 1 : go` create an infinite list n constant space, while `f () = 1 : f ()` do the same in unbounded space.

Comment: It kinda seems plausible, but I find it hard to wrap my mind around it. For one, I see no reason GHC cound not optimize this, if it is so easily done by hand.

Comment: @Kindaro It is not always an optimization, space wise. `let f () = ... in print (f ()) >> print somethingElse >> print (f ())` could free memory during the middle step, and reallocate it for the third step. Using `let x = ... in print x >> print somethingElse >> print x` will keep `x` in memory for the whole computation. This is useful to achieve memoization (which is what we need in the `fix`) example, but that is not always desirable. Sometimes, we do want to throw away precomputed results (especially large ones) and recompute them later when needed.

Comment: Well, if it gives tenfold speedup on any recursive function, I'd say it's a worthy tradeoff.